# Should i use Role based Authentification?

Tags: asp.net, api, authentication

I am planning to build a website where users can sell and buy stuff.

My question is if i should use role based authentification for my API or if i should create two complete different types of users. The sellers and the buyers.
The user should be able to decide if he/she wants to sign up as a seller or buyer.

What is the common way to achieve this?
Jakob

Comment: The best case scenario for this will be accomplished by use of Role based Authentication. Provide a radio button as an option selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Role based authentication will be more dynamic. Because, if your project be more complex in future, then your user type solution won't be enough. Also, you can easily give multiple roles for one user by role based authentication.